# How to center subscription form in bootstrap 4?

Tags: forms, css-position

```
<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>&copy; 2018, Matir Dokan, CSEDU</p>  
  <form class="form-inline">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
    <button type="button pull-right" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
  </form>
</footer>
```

[image]
I want to shift the email address and subscribe option in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class of  `justify-content-center`.

Edit :

```
 <form class="form-inline">
```

TO :

```
 <form class="form-inline justify-content-center">
```

[Demo with your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/UALIs3PAaMVVFezc7C8M?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow community.You need to `align="center"` inside the `<form>`
Try this code :

```
   <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
   <p>&copy; 2018, Matir Dokan, CSEDU</p>  
  <form class="form-inline" align="center">
 <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address">
 <button type="button pull-right" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
</form>
 </footer>
```